# select sum where condition is true and count > 3

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

- `FootballPlayers` with columns Id_footballplayer, Last_Name, Fisrt_Name, Age
- `Transfers` with columns Id_transfer, Name_club, price, date, acceptance (yes or no), code_footballplayer

How can I write a SQL query to select the last names of the players and the sum of the successful transfers carried out by them, the number of which exceeds 3?

I already wrote a query that displays the total amount of all successful transfers for each player

```
SELECT FootballPLayers.Last_Name, 
       SUM(CASE acceptance WHEN 'yes' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS amount_price
FROM  FootballPlayers 
  INNER JOIN Transfers ON FootballPlayers.ID_footballplayer = Transfers.code_footballplayer
GROUP BY FootballPlayers.Last_Name;
```

But I don’t know how to add a condition if the number of successful transfers is more than 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a group scenario, after the`GROUP BY` you probably want:

```sql
HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
```

The `HAVING` clause works very similarly to `WHERE`, but is applied differently.

---

An alternative would be the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT FootballPLayers.Last_Name,
        SUM(CASE acceptance WHEN 'yes' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS amount_price,
        COUNT(1) AS [Transfers]
    FROM  FootballPlayers 
    INNER JOIN Transfers ON FootballPlayers.ID_footballplayer = Transfers.code_footballplayer
    GROUP BY FootballPlayers.Last_Name
) x
WHERE x.Transfers > 3
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `count(1)`  is not faster than `count(*)`. Also: the question isn't tagged with `sql-server` so in general answers, should stick to standard SQL where `[Transfers]` would be an invalid identifier.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name unless you're saying  it is slower, I have literally nothing to say about the choice of * vs 1; and for SQL variants: indeed, if OP doesn't specify, then OP may need to tweak it to suit; seems to have been a good guess, though

Comment: @Marc Garvell https://searchoracle.techtarget.com/answer/COUNT-or-COUNT-1